# Unusually high system load after upgrading to Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: upgrade, kernel, kubuntu, 22.04, system

I was running Kubuntu 18.04 LTS all this while and finally decided to upgrade to the latest LTS release. Did an upgrade to 20.04 LTS and after booting into it the first time I noticed unusually high system load averages on htop, didn't think much of it at first. Decided to upgrade to Kubuntu 22.04 LTS right away, the process completed but there were some issues I ran into

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openmpi-bin
 mpi-default-bin
 libcoarrays-openmpi-dev:amd64
 libopenmpi-dev:amd64
 libboost-mpi-python1.74.0
```

but this was swiftly resolved from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464085/openmpi-bin-error-after-update-kubuntu-18-04-to-20-04).

Now, as I am running Kubuntu 22.04.1, I notice unusually high system load average even on Idle, not working on anything. But I can't see any process consuming high resources??

[image: htop screenshot]

Running OS and CPU:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Linux Inspiron-15-3567 5.15.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 07:51:15 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


Name:              Intel Core i5-7200U
Microarchitecture: Kaby Lake
Technology:        14nm
Max Frequency:     3.100 GHz
Cores:             2 cores (4 threads)
```

I don't understand how this is possible? Nothing is running but load averages go up to 13 and more! Used to be just fine on 18.04 around 1 or 2 on no load. How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried rebooting?

Comment: @RishonJR Yes, I did reboot it a few times. Still the same issue.

Comment: try ```sudo htop``` and see if you can find that resource. or else it is just a kernel issue.

try to use this script:https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh

make sure you use the 4.15 kernel. that should do the trick.

Comment: @RishonJR If it is a kernel issue and I roll back to 4.15, that is only supported until April 2023. What option do I have after that?

Comment: till then keep using 4.15. later on you can update it to an LTS kernel

Comment: Upon installing the v4.15.18 mainline kernel the system can't boot, runs into kernel panic. @RishonJR

Comment: press shift on boot, select the old kernel version. then remove the 4.15 kernel then try ```./ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -i ```

Comment: @RishonJR I didn't use the script. Just downloaded all the 4 files from the ppa and used dpkg to install. Did the same with 5.19 and 5.19.5 which allows my system to boot but the high load issue persists. The problem happened with 5.4 as well.

Comment: looking at your screenshot again, that is perfectly normal. I compared with my ubuntu(with kde) and it's the same amount of  load. what makes you say "high system load on kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS?

Comment: @RishonJR Your load averages hover around 10+ without any running programs?

Comment: 20% because I'm using a somewhat low end laptop(Core i5 2nd Gen). You haven't mentioned any specs, so I'm assuming that you have a decent speced laptop.

Comment: I mean proper specs, sorry.

Comment: @RishonJR, yea, so for my case it is not normal as you can see four logical threads in the screenshot, load average should definitely be less than 4 when no apps are running. These are abnormally high loads. Had to switch to manjaro for the time being to be able to work.

Comment: try booting a live USB of kubuntu. if still high CPU loads then that's just an kubuntu thing.